# How to show the congested value in bar chart or how to hide value=0 in ssrs?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

How to show the congested value in bar chart or how to hide value=0  in ssrs?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
=iif(item.Value=0,"",item.Value)
```

**EDIT**

```
=IIf(fields!Status.Value = 0, false, true)
```